# creating squares on event

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paint

I am trying to create a game with the same system as snake. I have created a window with a `JPanel` on it, given it a background and drawn lines to show the user the squares.

Board is 600x600 (601x601 for all to be visible).
Squares are 20x20.

Now I am trying to add a way to put coloured squares onto the board and also detect if a coloured square is there already ideally.

```
public class CreateWindow extends JFrame {

    JPanel GameArea;
    static JLayeredPane Java_Window;
    Image Background;

    public void CreateWindow() {
        Dimension Panel_Size = new Dimension(800, 800);
        this.setSize(800,800);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setVisible( true );
        this.setTitle("LineRage");
        getContentPane().setBackground(Color.white); 

        Java_Window = new JLayeredPane();
        this.add(Java_Window);
        Java_Window.setPreferredSize(Panel_Size);

        GameArea = new JPanel()
        {
            @Override
            public void paint(Graphics g) {
                g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                g.fillRect(0,0,601,601);

                g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
                // Cut map into sections
                int x;
                //draw vertical lines
                for(x = 0; x < 31; x++) {
                    g.drawLine(x*20,0,x*20,600);
                }    
                //draw horizontal lines
                for(x = 0; x < 31; x++) {
                    g.drawLine(0,x*20,600,x*20);
                }     
            }

            public void PaintSquare (int x,int y) {
                //Check if square painted

                //Paint square
                Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(x, y, 20, 20);
                GameArea.add(rect);
            }
        };
        Java_Window.add(GameArea, JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);
        GameArea.setBounds(20, 20, 601, 601);
        GameArea.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

So `Java_Window` (800x800) has a white background,
`Game_Area` (601x601) has black background with 32 lines up along and across it to divide it into squares.

```
public void PaintSquare (int x, int y) {
    //Check if square painted

    //Paint square
    Rectangle square = new Rectangle(x, y, 20, 20);
    GameArea.add(square);
}
```

`PaintSquare` will be called from another object (the main game) and check the background of the square, if it is free it will paint a square on it (20x20).

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, the question is, how can I create squares to occupy a space through calling the PaintSquare().

I have read a bunch of stuff online but nothing I have been able to make work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your exact question is unclear but here are some pointers:

- Use `paintComponent` rather than `paint` when doing custom painting in Swing. Don't forget to call `super.paintComponent(g)`.
- `java.awt.Rectangle` is not derived from `JComponent` (or `Component`) so can't be added to a container.
- One approach to take would be to use [fillRect](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#fillRect%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) and "paint" the squares:

Also, in Java, methods start with a *lowercase* letter. Adding this and the previous point together, you could do:

```
public void paintSquare(Graphics g, int x, int y) {
   g.fillRect(x, y, 20, 20);
}
```

Here, the `paintSquare` method would be called from `paintComponent`.

Comment: +1 best approach; see also this related [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3518047/230513).

Comment: Can fillRect be used after the JPanel has been created?

Answer (score 0):

Follow [Reimeus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15202157/300257)' advice, and in addition, you need to create a GUI model.

Define a Rectangle array the same size as the game board in a game model class.

```
Rectangle[][] board;
```

That way, you can test for an overlapping snake in your model class, rather than worry about what you've already painted.

Your paintComponent method becomes pretty simple.

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    model.draw(g);
}
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15120594/300257) for a fuller explanation.

Comment: Would an int 2 dimensional array be effective? Eventually there will be multiple users then a switch to find if free, a users snake is on there or another object?

Comment: An int array wouldn't be sufficient.  You model has to contain enough information to draw itself, which is why I used the Rectangle class.  You can define your own class and make it into a two dimensional array.  Your class would include the defining rectangle, and whatever other information you want to store in your model.

Comment: What if I used
For int[30][30]
switch (int[x][y])
case 1: paintSquare(g, x*20,y*20, Color.RED);

  paintSquare (Graphics g,int x,int y, Color c)
  g.setColor(c);
  g.fillRect(x, y, 20, 20);

Comment: @Chris Brown:  You don't seem to understand the difference between a game model and a game GUI yet.