# Draw array to canvas

Tags: java, arrays, java-canvas

I'm trying to draw objects onto a canvas from an array, but the thing is, I have no clue how to? This must include the position and sizes of the shapes, and there will be more than one type of shape. The code I've got so far(It's inefficient/bad though)

```
public class MCanvas extends Canvas {
    private Object[] world = {};

    public void paint(Graphics g){  
        try{  
           // How to paint all the shapes from world here?
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {  
              System.out.println(e.toString());  
        }  
      } 

}
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: *"but the thing is, I have no clue how to?"*  The thing is, that is not a question (even with shoving '?' on the end).  What is your specific question?  Also, why use AWT in this millennium?  Here we use Swing.

Comment: Don't forget to call super.paint first. What are the shapes?

Comment: @MadProgrammer They are dynamically added to the array, but mainly rectangles and ovals.

Comment: @AndrewThompson My question is how to draw shapes in the array to the canvas, and I've not seen any swing alternative for Canvas. I'm all open for change though.

Comment: This explanation might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15120594/300257

Comment: Are they java.awt.Shape's ?

Comment: @MadProgrammer No, at the moment I'm doing them by the java.awt.Rectangle class... etc

Comment: FYI java.awt.Rectangle extends from java.awt.Shap ;)

Comment: Ah, never knew that. Thanks for that.

Comment: *"I've not seen any swing alternative for Canvas."*  1) A `JPanel` (extended) is very similar to a `Canvas` 2) Alternately Swing can also display a `BufferedImage` in a `JLabel`, and we can obtain a `Graphics2D` from the image..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your using objects that extend from `java.awt.Shape`, you can translate and draw them by using a `Graphics2D` context

Since (some whe around Java 1.3/4), the paint engine is guaranteed to use `Graphics2D` instance.

```
public void paint(Graphics g){  
    super.paint(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
    for (Object o : world) {
        if (o instanceof Shape) {
            Shape shape = (Shape)o;
            //if the shape isn't created with 
            // a location, you can translate them
            shape.translate(...,...);
            g2d.setColor(....);
            g2d.draw(shape);
            //g2d.fill(...);
        }
    }
}
```

You might like to take a look at [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html) for more details.

Also, use a `JPanel` instead of `Canvas` and then override its `paintComponent` method

Have a look at [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details